# Strange Behavior from Split View in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I implemented the `SplitView` in my app as follow.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     LeftsideViewController *masterViewController = [[LeftsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftsideViewController" bundle:nil] ;
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] ;

    HomeViewController *detailViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
    masterViewController.homeViewController = detailViewController;

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init] ;
    [self.splitViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController,detailNavigationController,nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
     NSLog(@"VIEWs %@",[self.window subviews]);
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**Problem**

It is working fine in ios 6.

But in ios 7 it shows the some view which i did not included.
See my following image & the `extra view is in Pink Color`.
[image]

Comment: are you sure there is actually an extra view? to me it looks like the splitview is added to the view in portrait although it should be in landscape...

Answer (score 0):

```
float systemversion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue];

    if(systemversion>=7.0f)
    {

        self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
```

Try this code